# Writing data received from a socket to a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, sockets

I am currently receiving data from a windows computer to a linux system which has the following implementation. It reads the data and writes it to a file

```
char buffer[4096];   
int BUFSIZE=4096; 
std::ofstream file(INPUT_PS_FILE_NAME, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
while (bytes_read > 0)
{
     buffer[bytes_read] = 0; 
     bytes_read = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);  
     if(bytes_read>0) {
         file.write(buffer,BUFSIZE-1); 
         printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer); 
     }
}
```

Now sometimes in my file I would get a whole bunch of "\00\00\00\00\00..." in my file and sometimes its fine but never on the console of the machine.My understanding is this happens because `printf` when passed an array will print all the contents of an array until it meets a null character however `file.write` does not. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. Also inorder to resolve this issue is there a way for me to have `file.write` behave like printf where it only prints until a NULL termination is found ?

Comment: Well, it is going to write whatever you got back in the buffer.

Comment: I would not like to print \0\0

Comment: you should not write more bytes than you read, you should use something like `file.write(buffer,bytes_read)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `while` loop that checks `bytes_read` before `recv()` has been called for the first time.  Use a `do/while` loop instead.  And you are not outputting the read data correctly, either.  You need to take `bytes_read` into account when outputting the data.  You are writing too many bytes to `file`, and not null-terminating the buffer for `printf()`.

Try this instead:

```
char buffer[4096];   
std::ofstream file(INPUT_PS_FILE_NAME, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
do
{
     bytes_read = recv(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);  
     if (bytes_read > 0) {
         file.write(buffer, bytes_read); 
         printf("Buffer: %.*s\n", bytes_read, buffer); 
         //or: printf("Buffer: %*.*s\n", bytes_read, bytes_read, buffer); 
     }
}
while (bytes_read > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. @mpromonet suggested this and it worked. Thanks for clearing this up

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. `printf` (and all is variants) write formatted text to the output stream till a NULL character (`\0`) is found in the format string, and string parameters (`%s`) follow the same logic. `write` in the other hand deals with bytes and "ignores" what the values are. It will write NULLs without distinction.

If you want to write formatted text to a file, use `fprintf`.